# Comunicação entre dois Controllers AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

Tenho um objeto que gostaria de compartilhar com outros `Controllers`, pensei em duas maneiras, a primeira seria utilizar `$rootScope` e na outra utilizar um `Service`. Optei pela segunda maneira e criei o seguinte service:

```
AuditoriaAPP.factory('Service', function() {
 var Service = {
    solicitacoes: {}
  };
 return Service;
});
```

No 1º Controller, que é onde está meu objeto que desejo compartilhar faço dessa forma:

```
Service.solicitacoes = solicitacao;
```

Até ai tudo bem, o objeto é atribuído com sucesso e consigo recupera-lo no 2º `Controller`:

```
$scope.solicitacoes = Service.solicitacoes;
```

O problema é que quando atualizo a página o objeto passa a ser vazio. Como posso fazer uma comunicação entre esses `Controllers` sem que o objeto fique vazio ao atualizar a página?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvi o problema com a ajuda do @lbotinelly, como o mesmo me disse, todo acesso ao service sempre irá inicializar o objeto e uma alternativa seria utilizar o `localStorage`.

No 1º `Controller` envio o objeto para o `locaStorage`

```
$localStorage.solicitacao = solicitacao;
```

E depois recupero o objeto nos demais `controllers`:

```
var solicitacao = $localStorage.solicitacao
```

Após o uso posso deletar o objeto dessa forma: `delete $localStorage.solicitacao`

**OBS:** Utilizei a biblioteca [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage) para trabalhar com o `localStorage`